# Entity Framework 6 throws migration exception when trying to create a context with Effort

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, effort

I'm trying to use Effort to test my application but if code-first migrations are enabled on the context then it throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Migrations is enabled for context 'XDbContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.

If I disable migrations then it all works fine.

How do I stop entity from even considering the migrations for the purposes of my tests.

Answer (score 6):

I kept getting the same error in my unit testing project. I solved it by modifying the TestInitialize function by calling the CreateIfNotExist() function

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        DbConnection connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();

        context = new MyAccessContext(connection);
        context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        service = new YourClass(context);
    }
```

Comment: Had the problem described by Steve with Effort, Entity Framework 6.0.0 and a DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer. Adding the `CreateIfNotExists()` call as suggested above fixed it.

However, adding the `context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();` was no longer necessary after updating to Entity Framework 6.1.3.

Comment: I had the same issue and upgrading to Entity Framework 6.1.3 solved it, as Lauri Harpf mentioned.

Comment: Note: If you install Effort.EF6 before Entity Framework, Effort will ship with a lower version of Entity Framework than v 6.1.3, which means that it will not work. You need to update it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Several methods. You can set your database initializer to null:

```
Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
```

You can disable the initializer in web.config: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Initializers

If your model is already up to date, just make sure you have automigrations disabled:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
```